# Finding the $ \int_0^\infty x^n \theta e^{-x\theta}dx$

Tags: probability, integration

Question ask to find the n-th moment of $ \theta e^{-x\theta} $ for x>0, and 0 elsewhere.

Which would be written as:  $ \int_0^\infty x^n \theta e^{-x\theta}dx$

Solving this problem, I attempted integrating by parts:

$-x^n  e^{-x\theta}+n\int_0^\infty x^{n-1} e^{-x\theta}dx$

Applying another integration by parts:

$-x^n  e^{-x\theta}-{n \over \theta} x^{n-1}  e^{-x\theta}+n(n-1)\int_0^\infty x^{n-2} e^{-x\theta}dx$

Seeing a pattern, I have:

$-e^{-x\theta}[x^n + {n\over\theta} x^{n-1}+...+{n!\over\theta^n}]_0^\infty$

I feel that I am either very close or completely wrong.

The inner bracket seems very familiar as well.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I guess you mean $\int_0^{\infty}$ rather than $\int_0^n$ in the 2nd line. And I presume $\theta$ is a fixed parameter, and you are integrating with respect to $x$.

Comment: \infty ... ? ... what are you integrating with respect to ?

Comment: My apologies for the ambiguity, I believe it is completely fixed.

Comment: Now evaluate the integral at the two limits.  As $x$ goes to $\infty, e^{-x\theta}$ goes to zero more powerfully than any polynomial can grow and the expression equals $0.$  When $x= 0, e^{-x\theta} = 1$ all the terms of the polynomial except for the constant term equal 0, leaving $\frac {n!}{\theta^n}$

Comment: You are correct Doug. I was too focused on trying to find a pattern to simplify the problem, I simply forgot to input the 2 limits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments the expression you found simplifies to $\frac{n!}{\theta^n}$.

One can also proceed in such fashion,

Noticing that:

$$f(\theta)=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\theta x}dx =\frac{1}{\theta}$$

So that,

$$f'(\theta)=\int_{0}^{\infty} -xe^{-\theta x} dx=\frac{-1}{\theta^2}$$

$$f''(\theta)=\int_{0}^{\infty} x^2e^{-\theta x}  dx=\frac{1(2)}{\theta^3}$$

Continuing in this fashion we see,

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^n e^{-\theta x} dx=\frac{n!}{\theta^{n+1}}$$

From which the result follows by multiplying both sides by $\theta$.

Comment: Wow, short and beautiful!

Comment: Thanks, differentiation under the integral sign is a pretty standard technique for many integrals.

Comment: I will keep that in mind. I just started reading some calculus/probability theory books. Unfortunately my school offers only basic high school algebra.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)

$$
\Gamma(z) = \int_0^{+\infty}{\rm d}x~ x^{z-1}e^{-x}
$$

So that

\begin{eqnarray}
I_n(\theta) &=& \int_0^{+\infty}{\rm d}x~\theta x^ne^{-\theta x} \stackrel{u=\theta x}{=} \frac{1}{\theta^n}\int_0^{+\infty}{\rm d}u ~x^u e^{-u} \\
&=& \frac{1}{\theta^n}\Gamma(n+1) = \frac{n!}{\theta^n}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: I am unaware of gamma function. I'm currently reading about expected values.

Comment: @manmoon The important property of this function is that $\Gamma(n + 1) = n!$, which is not that difficult to prove, but I believe the answer that *Ahmed* gave you is much more elegant

Answer (score 6):

In this case, the moment-generating function is a simple way to find all the moments:
$$ E[e^{tX}] = \int_0^{\infty} e^{tx} \theta e^{-\theta x} \, dx = \frac{\theta}{\theta-t}. $$
We can now find the $n$th moment from the coefficient of $t^n$:
$$ \frac{\theta}{\theta-t} = \frac{1}{1-t/\theta} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\theta^n}t^n. $$
The moment-generating function is an exponential generating function for the moments, so
$$ E[X^n] = \frac{n!}{\theta^n}. $$